# Missing Unity Desktop /w SLiM Login Manager

Tags: unity, command-line, shortcut-keys, login, login-screen

Not too long ago I installed SLiM <sub>(Simple Login Manager)</sub> as my Login Manager for Ubuntu 13.04 just to give it a try out to replace the default Ubuntu Login Manager.

After getting SLiM successfully installed, I tested it out by logging out and then back in again, however after logging in again the Unity Desktop UI is missing, and wont show up again until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in `unity` into Terminal to bring it back up again, I just wish to know how I can get Unity to load properly after logging in with SLiM so I don't have to do this on every login.

Another issue I have with SLiM, or not SLiM itself but Ubuntu, I created a new normal user, however when I try to login with that user I get an error saying

> Failed to execute login command

and returns me back to the Login of SLiM, I did a little reading on Google, but nothing too specific on how to fix this issue of user login. I tried creating this new user via CLI, but I think I might of screwed it up even though I typed it right, as all I typed was;

```
adduser --comment "temporary user" user001
```

Not sure if that was the right way of creating a new user, but correct me if I'm wrong. I'm trying to learn how to add and create new users through the CLI instead of the GUI as a good practice if I ever needed to test something.